# custom thumbnail image size not working

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

1. I added below code in theme's function.php

> add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
>   add_image_size(
>   'thumb-small', 200, 150, true );

and  `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb-small'); ?>` this in theme's file.

2. I tried this also in function.php

> function add_custom_sizes() {
>       add_image_size( 'idea-thumb', 146, 141, true ); 
>    }
>
> add_action('after_setup_theme','add_custom_sizes');

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('idea-thumb'); ?>` this in theme's file.

3. `the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );`  // Other resolutions

But above three condition are not working.

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>` //this is working with 150 * 150px as default size.

what i had done mistake.

Comment: old existing images will not resize automatically with newly defined image size. You will have to regenerate them again. Use [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin to generate thumbnails of all defined sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used [**Regenerate Thumbnails**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin to generate thumbnails